# What's Reefbane for?

Tags: path-of-exile

I recently found [Reefbane](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Reefbane), a unique "fishing rod". I cannot understand its usefulness, and I am under the impression that it is an "inside joke". Is this right? Or are there some legitimate uses for this item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fishing is an ongoing joke in the game. You can't really do anything with fishing rods or fishing items except collecting and/or selling them.

Fishing items are extremely rare and popular among collectors. Some rods sell for multiple exalted orbs so they're not completely useless if you find a buyer.

Always check [poe.trade](http://poe.trade/) for the current price of the rod in your league.